# org.json.JSONException: ApiKeyError

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I have integrated adobe creative SDK with my application successfully. Its running successfully but it throwing this exception .

```
W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: ApiKeyError
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsManifestDownloader.generateParser(CdsManifestDownloader.java:69)
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsManifestDownloader.download(CdsManifestDownloader.java:53)
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsServiceAbstract.downloadManifest(CdsServiceAbstract.java:360)
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsServiceAbstract.downloadAndProcessManifest(CdsServiceAbstract.java:382)
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsServiceAbstract.handleCdsDownload(CdsServiceAbstract.java:226)
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.creativesdk.aviary.internal.cds.CdsServiceAbstract.onHandleIntent(CdsServiceAbstract.java:137)
W/System.err:     at com.adobe.android.common.os.AdobeIntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(AdobeIntentService.java:66)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
W/System.err:     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same issue.